# .prependTo() and .insertAfter() without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could you please tell me how to use below function without jQuery?

```
jQuery('<div id="rich-content"></div>').prependTo(".html-content.detail-content")
```

I would like to prepend

```
'<div id="rich-content"></div>' to '<div class="html-content detail-content"></div>'
```

Kindly assist

Comment: do you want to do it with javascript?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add this through JavaScript

Comment: @Mamun answered your question.

Comment: when I tried to trigger the code provided by @Mamun in console it shows as
"undefined"

Comment: Because you are not giving any text in your div id="rich-content". if you give any text, it will be fine. for example you give "test" text in your div and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) with the position parameter value as `'afterbegin'` which will insert the *htmlString* just before the first child of the target element.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.html-content.detail-content'),
    elChild = '<div id="rich-content">Test</div>';

// Prepend it
el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', elChild);
```

```html
<div class="html-content detail-content"></div>
```

Comment: when I tried to trigger this code in console it shows as "undefined"

Comment: Because you are not giving any text in your div id="rich-content". if you give any text, it will be fine.. for example you give "test" text in your div and see.

Comment: @RohithP, you did not mention much in the question, I have provided an example in my answer which shows the code should work accordingly:)